# Runs smoothly, but output is not correct

Tags: python

Given 3 int values, a b c, return their sum. However, if any of the values is a teen -- in the range 13..19 inclusive -- then that value counts as 0, except 15 and 16 do not count as a teens. Write a separate helper "def fix_teen(n):"that takes in an int value and returns that value fixed for the teen rule. In this way, you avoid repeating the teen code 3 times (i.e. "decomposition"). Define the helper below and at the same indent level as the main no_teen_sum().

here's my code:

```
#Given 3 int values, a b c, return their sum. However, if any of the values is a teen -- in the range #13..19 inclusive -- then that value counts as 0, except 15 and 16 do not count as a teens. Write a #separate helper "def fix_teen(n):"that takes in an int value and returns that value fixed for the teen #rule. In this way, you avoid repeating the teen code 3 times (i.e. "decomposition"). Define the helper #below and at the same indent level as the main no_teen_sum().
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
  a = fix_teen(a)
  b = fix_teen(b)
  c = fix_teen(c)
  return(a+b+c)
  
def fix_teen(n):
  if n<=13 and n>=19 and n != 15 and n != 16:
    n = 0
  return(n)
```

Don't know why this doesn't work. I'm pretty sure my code is correct but my algorithm is wrong. Also this is my first question please correct me if my format is incorrect.

Comment: n<=19 ........ .

Answer (score 3):

You might mean `if n>=13 and n<=19 and n != 15 and n != 16`, because with the greater than and less than signs swapped no integer will ever fulfill the condition.

Comment: Thanks!  I fixed it and it turned out right

Answer (score 1):

As Chris pointed out, you have the operators the wrong way around. You need `if n>=13 and n<=19`, but have `if n<=13 and n>=19`.

Comment: unrelated to topic but I am being banned from posting every one or two questions. I have problems with my code a lot, is there a way to make my questions better so that nobody would dislike them?

Comment: Also, I've already tried searching my bugs up